# Monero Light Client

Tags: mnemonic-seed, light-wallet, third-party-wallets, jaxx

Is there any light client for Monero where I can create and import private keys/mnemonic-seed and send and receive transactions like electrum for Bitcoin / Dash ?

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/228/) addresses part of your question:

> The lightwallet by jwinterm is probably most similar thing to an SPV
>   wallet so far https://getmonero.org/getting-started/choose
>
> shen-noether is working on a mobile wallet that will connect to a
>   remote node https://hellomonero.com/tags/shen-noether

Jaxx and Exodus wallets are also in [development](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/897)

[Mnemonic seeds](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/97) are avaible for Monero in several [different forms](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/63)

Comment: this lightwallet doesn't work for me :/ 
i am not able to import my mnemonic-seed . failure all the time 

any other way to import my mnemonic-seed ? on mymonero, i have to pay 10XMR to get my history, so i cant use the balance without it?

Comment: works now, forgot the .dll s

Comment: @coinling glad to hear it is working now!

Comment: Unfortunately it just shut down after almost synced and now if i want to open it and type in the password it shuts down immediately all the time...

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean "light" to mean that the wallet does not keep a copy of the blockchain.  Well, if you have a node to point the wallet at, whether it be a trusted external node or whether it be your little Raspberry Pi for example, then you can configure monero-wallet-cli to act as a light client.  Actually, very little configuration is needed at all.  See [this post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-do-i-use-a-computer-with-a-wallet-to-access-a-headless-node-at-my-home) for how to do it on your internal network.

If you use monero-wallet-cli, it uses mnemonic seeds, and it has full wallet functionality (aside from it not currently having a GUI wrapped around it).