# why is the RPC version mismatched?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc, windows, daemon, ubuntu

I am attempting to use monero wallet on ubuntu 16.04 by attaching to a daemon on windows 7 in the same LAN, both are running version 0.10.0.0 Wolfram Warptangent, but using the command `./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address 192.168.0.18:18080` gives the following error: `Error: Daemon uses a different RPC version that the wallet: 192.168.0.18:18080. Either update one of them, or use --allow-mismatched-daemon-version.` I tried using --allow-mismatched-daemon-version but I still get this error: `Error: refresh failed: no connection to daemon. Please make sure daemon is running.. Blocks received: 0`

On the daemon I check with the status command and I have `Height: 1188586/1188586 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 37.33 MH/s, v3, up to date, 50+18 connections` so it is certainly running and accepting incoming connections.

Comment: When you used the `--allow-mistmatched-daemon` command, you also used the `--daemon-host` command as well, correct?  If not try that.  If so, then I'm still baffled.  On running the daemon, you ran `--rpc-bind-ip`command using the node's IP, correct?

Comment: nope, I didn't use rpc-bind-ip. it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions noted in the answer to this question?

[How do I use a computer with a wallet to access a headless node at my home?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-do-i-use-a-computer-with-a-wallet-to-access-a-headless-node-at-my-home)

I notice you mentioned `--daemon-address` as opposed to `--daemon-host`.  I'm not sure if both those addresses work and are interchangeable.

Comment: i restarted the daemon with rpc-bind-ip and the wallet is working as needed. does this mean i cannot use the daemon from a remote IP now? or will it still work since the NAT is forwarding the ports from the WAN IP to a the local IP? i don't plan on needing to use it from a remote IP but this is the next question my thought process went to.

Comment: I'm curious about the same thing.  I think the answer is you definitely can.  You probably need to register your IP with DynDNS or No-IP, since your home IP is likely not static.  You should look into this more. Then IMO, once you have more knowledge on how you *think* it would work, this would be a good new question to ask.

Comment: It just occurred to me (duh) that the answer to your follow-up is almost definitely what I already pointed out, with the added point that all the details relevant to connecting to a remote note will apply.  The only difference is you'll substitute your IP or chosen DNS entry (web address) for the remote node's web address.